# How to check if WebResource exists for a specific language?

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-globalresources

I have an `App_GlobalResources` folder populated with `.resx` files, e.g. `WebResources.de.resx`, `WebResources.fr.resx`.

How can I programatically check using C# that a specific WebResource file exists (or not) for a particular language (e.g. en, fr, de)?

Comment: At what point in the request lifecycle do you need to check this, and why? These resources are designed to gracefully fall back to defaults. What action would you take if a resource file were missing?

Comment: @DanWilson I have an "how to" page. I want to show a link to the how to page and allow access to it only if a translation exists for it.

Comment: The most straightforward way I can imagine is to get the absolute path to the `App_GlobalResources` directory and call `File.Exists()` on the target file.

Comment: A more granular check can be done by using   System.Resources.ResourceReader resourceFile = new System.Resources.ResourceReader("file.resx"); This gives an exception if the file is not existing or if not in proper format.

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using

```
System.Resources.ResourceReader resourceFile = new System.Resources.ResourceReader("file.resx");
```

This gives an exception if the file is not existing or if not in proper format.

Comment: Note that logic via exceptions is horribly slow and can quite easily take down your site if this method is called a lot. I would strongly recommend against doing this.

Comment: The other option is using File.Exists but then it does not peep into the file :-)

Comment: Well I would much rather try and figure out why OP is even doing this in the first place. If no method exists to do this in the framework, that suggests it's not something commonly done. Possibly an XY problem...